# Couple of questions about how objects work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

node1 = Node (1)
node1.next = Node (2)

x = node1
```

When I say "x = node1", what exactly is x? As in is it a pointer to where node1 is stored or does it create a separate identical copy of the linked list? Or is it neither

I ask because if I were to add...

```
x = Node (100)
```

...node1 is not altered. But if I added...

```
x.data = 100
```

...instead, node1 would be altered in that the first value in the linked list would now be 100.

Also if I were to add...

```
print (node1)
```

...I'd get something like "<**main**.Node object at 0x0000019599685FD0>", is the 0x0000019599685FD0 part the memory address of the object?

Comment: It's a pointer (or reference). Assignment operator (`=`) creates a new variable, destroying the meaning of old `x`, while `x.data = 100` modifies the instance attribute (`data`) of the existing object. And yes, that's the memory location of the object.

Comment: `x` is a *name in the global namespace* that is referencing a `Node` object. You can think of it like a pointer, but Python doesn't really have pointers.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `0x0000019599685FD0` is an *implementation detail, in CPython, it is the address of the PyObject header. The only reason it is there is to give you a unique number to serve to disambiguate the default string representation, inherited from. `object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node1 = Node(1)`: `node1` is a reference to the object created using `Node(1)`.

The object's identifier is `0x0000019599685FD0` where in CPython (Python's default implementation) happens to be where the object is located.

`x = node1` makes `x` refer to the same object in `node1`.

`x.data = 100` changes attribute data of the object referenced by `x`.

`x = Node (100)` makes `x` reference a completely new object.

I highly suggest visualizing it using tools such as [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display).